# Main parts of a post

Tags: terminology

I'm learning [a Merriam-Webster tutorial](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/couple-few-several-use).

[image]

When talking about writing, I guess there are some terms to refer to main parts of a post.

Here are some words I can imagine.

1. is the **title** of the post
2. is the **subtitle** of the post
3. is the **summary/brief** of the post
4. is the **opening** of the post
5. is the **title** of the first section

Am I using them correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be happy with those terms.  Perhaps I'd use "Heading of the first section" rather than repeat "title".  And "Abstract" is an alternative to "summary".  The summary of an article in a journal is usually called an abstract.

I wouldn't call the whole thing a "post".  It's a bit longer than a "blog post". Most posts wouldn't have much structure like sections. I'd call it an article, although the distinction is blurred.